# Execute/Run Visual Basic Script in relative folder with `\write18` during compilation

Tags: shell-escape, directory

To run a visual basic script named `readCSV.vbs` in/before/during latex compilation, I have the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% line3:
%\immediate\write18{readCSV.vbs} %Works If you put it next to main
% line5:
\immediate\write18{"/CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs"} % Does not work

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If I: 
 1. Put the `readCSV.vbs` directly in the same folder as `main.txt`
 2. Open cmd and browse to the directory, e.g. `E:/folder path with a space in it/project folder/` that contains the `readCSV.vbs`
 3. Execute command: `pdflatex --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex`

It works fine with the line 3 uncommented, meaning it compiles and runs the script directly in the same folder as `Main.tex`.

However when I run it with line 5, commenting line 3, it does not work. (All below commands are executed from directory: `E:/folder path with a space in it/project folder/` which contains the `main.tex`.)

The error message is:

> `(e:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))The system cannot find the path specified.`

### Edits in response to the comments:

The option:

```
\immediate\write18{"CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs"}
```

Returns:

> `e:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))'CsvTasks' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`

And the option:

```
\immediate\write18{./CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs}
```

Returns:

> `(e:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`

And the option:

```
\immediate\write18{"E:/folder path with a space in it/project folder/CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs"}
```

Works. However, I intend to make it runnable on different pc's, which is why I am either looking for:

- A functioning `\write18` command that only requires the subfolder
- A way to get the absolute path of `main.tex` into the latex so that I can paste the subfolder behind it.

For completeness: I am running this on a windows 10 pc with Texmaker.

### Question

How can I run the `readCSV.vbs` from latex with the `\write18`command from sub/relative directory `/CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs`?

Comment: you have `/CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs` which means the file is at the root of the filesystem so `c:\CsvTasks\readCSV.vbs` if that is not where the file is then you are perhaps looking for `CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs` or equivalently `./CsvTasks/readCSV.vbs` which would be a file in the CsvTasks folder of the working directory

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your suggestions, I have tried them both, though I have not yet managed to get them working. Indeed the absolute path to the relative/sub folder does work. So I will be looking for a way to get the directory of the main as a dynamic function, so that it will also work in other scenarios. Ofcourse a relative path would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Oh sorry vbs is not an executable it's a visual basic script so you need  the first argument to be the script runtime so something like `\write18{cscript CsvTasks\string\readCSV.vbs}`

Comment: but as you said the absolute path worked perhaps I am wrong that you need cscript explicitly. Note that the paths are relative to the directory from which you run tex, nit from the file. If you start with `pdflatex mydocument` that is the same thing, but if you started via `pdflatex /documents/myfile.tex` then the working directory for the executable may be the root or your desktop or whatever, depending on how you set things up.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration, that the relative path is relative to the "cmd/compile-invoking"-command does indeed complicate or disable my intended goal with relative folder. However, it does not explain why it does not work so far, since I indeed invoked it from the folder that contains the `main.tex` in cmd.

Comment: sorry I don't have a windows texlive to try, so I can't help further, someone else will come past though....